# How to add library to app dependency list in QtCreator

Tags: android, qt, shared-libraries, qt-creator, qtquick2

I'm trying to create QtQuick extention, and can't understand, how I can add it to my app project, that it was compiling, picks, and for android, packing in one apk?

I have:

```
dev_root
  all.pro
  app
    app.pro
  ext
    ext.pro
```

**all.pro**

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs

SUBDIRS += \
    app \
    ext
```

I try to open all.pro in QtCreator, both app.pro and ext.pro opens, seems to be good. The .pro file with TEMPLATE = subdirs, as I understand, , is an analogue of MSVC solution. In MSVC, I can simply specify the dependency, and lib will be built before building exe, but in qtCreator I can't find such feature.

I try to do as writes in net - open app.pro, right click on it, "Add library..." — "Internal library". In dialog "Choise the project file f the library to link to" combobox is always empty, and I can't select my library.

What I'm doing wrong?

**UPD1**

Some of probles was fixed by adding

```
ext.subdir         = ext
app.depends        = ext
```

into all.pro

But when I try to build and deploy app to my android device, I have got an error:

```
Starting: "D:\Qt\Tools\mingw482_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" INSTALL_ROOT="F:/work/app-project/build-app-Android_for_armeabi_GCC_4_8_Qt_5_3_1Debug/android-build" install
cd ext/ && ( test -e Makefile || D:/Qt/5.3/android_armv5/bin/qmake.exe F:/work/app-project/app/ext/ext.pro -spec android-g++ CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=declarative_debug CONFIG+=qml_debug -o Makefile ) && D:/Qt/Tools/mingw482_32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile install
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'f:/work/app-project/build-app-Android_for_armeabi_GCC_4_8_Qt_5_3_1-Debug/ext'
/usr/bin/sh: D:MinGWmsys1.0workapp-projectbuild-app-Android_for_armeabi_GCC_4_8_Qt_5_3_1-Debugandroid-build/libs/armeabi/: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/sh: D:MinGWmsys1.0workapp-projectbuild-app-Android_for_armeabi_GCC_4_8_Qt_5_3_1-Debugandroid-build/libs/armeabi/: No such file or directory
```

It seems like path passed to MSYS contains MS slashes - '\', and MSYS simple eats it. How I can correct this?

**UPD2**

Building extention process fixed, but I can't understand, how I can add dependencies using QtCreator, not manually editing `.pro` file

**ext.pro**

```
TEMPLATE = lib
TARGET = ext
QT += qml quick declarative
CONFIG += qt plugin

TARGET = $$qtLibraryTarget($$TARGET)
uri = com.example.ext

# Input
SOURCES += \
    Plugin.cpp \
    ext.cpp

HEADERS += \
    Plugin.h \
    ext.h

OTHER_FILES = qmldir

!equals(_PRO_FILE_PWD_, $$OUT_PWD) {
    copy_qmldir.target = $$OUT_PWD/qmldir
    copy_qmldir.depends = $$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/qmldir
    copy_qmldir.commands = $(COPY_FILE) \"$$replace(copy_qmldir.depends, /, $$QMAKE_DIR_SEP)\" \"$$replace(copy_qmldir.target, /, $$QMAKE_DIR_SEP)\"
    QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += copy_qmldir
    PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$copy_qmldir.target
}

qmldir.files = qmldir
unix {
    installPath = $$[QT_INSTALL_QML]/$$replace(uri, \\., /)
    qmldir.path = $$installPath
    target.path = $$installPath
    INSTALLS += target qmldir
}
```

Comment: Can you add your `ext.pro`? It seems like in there is a linux shell command (/usr/bin/sh) which cannot exist on Windows.

Comment: Problem was that the MSYS was found by QMAKE and it's sh.exe used, which eats slashes. Removing MSYS from PATH solves problem. In addition, the `test` required, and I wrote `.bat` file for replacement